# Add category description to list of category with taxonomy image

Tags: images, taxonomy

I'm using the Taxonomy Images plugin.
Would like to list categories with their thumbnails AND descriptions. Code below give a list of categories (titles are linked to category archive) and thumbnails. I can't figure out how to add category description.

```
    $terms = apply_filters( 'taxonomy-images-get-terms', '', array('taxonomy' => 'category') );

if ( ! empty( $terms ) ) {

  echo '<div class="issue">';

  foreach( (array) $terms as $term ) {
      echo '<h3><a href="' . esc_url( get_term_link( $term, $term->taxonomy ) ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a></h3>';
      echo '<div class="grid col-60"><a href="' . esc_url( get_term_link( $term, $term->taxonomy ) ) . '">' . wp_get_attachment_image( $term->image_id, 'thumbnail-small' ) . '</a></div>';
      echo '<div class="grid col-780"><h4>In this issue</h4><p>[CATEGORY DESCRIPTION SHOULD GO HERE]</p></div>';
  }

  echo '</div>';

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you might try to replace

```
echo '<div class="grid col-780"><h4>In this issue</h4><p>[CATEGORY DESCRIPTION SHOULD GO HERE]</p></div>';
```

with:

```
echo '<div class="grid col-780"><h4>In this issue</h4><p>'. $term->description. '</p></div>';
```

i.e. `$term->description` to get the description part.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Didn't work exactly how you wrote it, but works like this:
`echo '<div class="grid col-780 fit">'. $term->description . '</div></div>';`

I was so over-complicating it! Thanks a lot

Comment: hehe thanks, I fixed this silly mistake I made ;-)